# Where can I find this LinkedIn Plugin?

Tags: plugins, embed, social-networking, linkedin-api

Recently, I had a client send me a screenshot of what appeared to be a LinkedIn Plugin. I asked the client where they got it from, but they couldn't remember, but wanted me to replicate it on their new site... I've looked all over and couldn't seem to find anything exactly like this. I am not very well-versed when it comes to LinkedIn, so the answer may be right under my nose.

Would anyone out there know where I can find this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCxUj.png

I've looked through http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins, but couldn't find anything that had 'Latest Discussions' or 'Most Popular'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot you've attached looks like a custom API integration emulating the widget that is found in LinkedIn hosted groups on LinkedIn.com. There are no LinkedIn-supported plugins available that can provide this functionality at this time. From the forums, a post from a LinkedIn employee:

https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/12044#comment-12044

Answer (score 0):

[Agorava LinkedIn](https://github.com/agorava/agorava-linkedin) is an connector to LinkedIn for Agorava. And [Agorava](http://agorava.org) Socializer also supports LinkedIn beside other popular social networking services like Facebook or Twitter.